Enable RED on webrtcbin for audio
I construct a pipeline in C++, receive an SDP offer and respond to it. It works alright with 'just' OPUS but sometimes the audio's not great, so I was looking into using RED, but am having trouble getting it to work. I've found a way of enabling RED here (https://github.com/hissinger/gstreamer-webrtcbin-demo/blob/main/webrtc-sendrecv.c - lines 306-317), but that is for when I am making the offer, not responding.
Code snippets
For the generic OPUS, I construct the pipeline in a mix of ways (hopefully the below is enough to give the idea):
GstElement * _audio_depay = gst_element_factory_make("rtpopusdepay", "webrtcaudiodepay");
GstElement * _audio_dec = gst_element_factory_make("opusdec", "audiodecode");
GstElement * _audio_converter_caps = gst_caps_new_simple("audio/x-raw", "format", G_TYPE_STRING, "S16LE", "layout", G_TYPE_STRING, "interleaved", NULL);

std::stringstream ss;
ss << "webrtcbin name=webrtcbin "
   << "appsrc name=webrtcaudioappsrc ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! audiorate ! "
   << "opusenc inband-fec=true audio-type=restricted-lowdelay bitrate-type=cbr packet-loss-percentage=100 bandwidth=1102 dtx=true ! rtpopuspay dtx=true pt=111 ! "
   << "application/x-rtp,media=audio,encoding-name=OPUS,payload=111 ! webrtcbin. ";

GError * error = nullptr;
_pipeline = gst_parse_launch(ss.str().c_str(), &error);

GstElement * _webrtc = gst_bin_get_by_name(GST_BIN(_pipeline), "webrtcbin");

I then listen to the pad-added signal from _webrtcbin to link the elements I've constructed by hand to make a pipeline that looks like
webrtcbin -> rtpopusdepay -> opusdec -> audioconvert -> appsink

Trying to use RED
The SDP offer I receive from my browser contains a RED entry (I've edited the below to save space):
m=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 63 9 102 0 8 13 110 126
...
a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
a=rtcp-fb:111 transport-cc
a=fmtp:111 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1
a=rtpmap:63 red/48000/2
a=fmtp:63 111/111
...

I've tried munging this offer to place 63 ahead of 111 in the m line, and I then submit that to my webrtcbin to produce the answer.
GstSDPMessage * sdp = nullptr;

gst_sdp_message_new_from_text(sdp_data.c_str(), &sdp); // sdp_data is the string sent from the browser after I've munged it

GstWebRTCSessionDescription * offer = nullptr;
offer = gst_webrtc_session_description_new(GST_WEBRTC_SDP_TYPE_OFFER, sdp);

auto promise = gst_promise_new();
g_signal_emit_by_name(_webrtc, "set-remote-description", offer, promise);
gst_promise_wait(promise);

gst_webrtc_session_description_free(offer);
gst_promise_unref(promise);

promise = gst_promise_new_with_change_func(on_answer, this, NULL);
g_signal_emit_by_name(_webrtc, "create-answer", NULL, promise);

However, looking at the answer I produce, it still defaults to using OPUS (111). Maybe webrtcbin uses the ordering of the rtpmap (though I don't think it should, right?), but I think it's more likely to be because the webrtcbin is linked to opus-based elements, and therefore the linking necessitates using OPUS.
I've tried manually adding elements to the pipeline, so that the pipeline looks like
appsrc -> opusenc -> rtpopuspay -> rtpulpfecenc -> rtpredenc -> webrtcbin
webrtcbin -> rtpreddec -> rtpstorage -> rtpssrcdemux -> rtpjitterbuffer -> rtpulpfecdec -> rtpopusdepay -> opusdec -> audioconvert -> appsink

(Trying to recreate the pipelines mentioned in https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/rtp/rtpredenc.html?gi-language=c and https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/rtp/rtpreddec.html?gi-language=c#rtpreddec)
At the moment this produces a receive only element, with the warning when I run:
0:00:13.919634921 41106 0x7756b8004940 WARN               webrtcbin gstwebrtcbin.c:4636:_create_answer_task:<webrtcbin> did not find compatible transceiver for offer caps application/x-rtp, media=(string)audio, payload=(int)63, clock-rate=(int)48000, encoding-name=(string)RED, encoding-params=(string)2, 111/111=(string)1; application/x-rtp, media=(string)audio, payload=(int)111, clock-rate=(int)48000, encoding-name=(string)OPUS, encoding-params=(string)2, minptime=(string)10, useinbandfec=(string)1, rtcp-fb-transport-cc=(boolean)true; application/x-rtp, media=(string)audio, payload=(int)9, clock-rate=(int)8000, encoding-name=(string)G722; application/x-rtp, media=(string)audio, payload=(int)0, clock-rate=(int)8000, encoding-name=(string)PCMU; application/x-rtp, media=(string)audio, payload=(int)8, clock-rate=(int)8000, encoding-name=(string)PCMA; application/x-rtp, media=(string)audio, payload=(int)13, clock-rate=(int)8000, encoding-name=(string)CN; application/x-rtp, media=(string)audio, payload=(int)110, clock-rate=(int)48000, encoding-name=(string)TELEPHONE-EVENT; application/x-rtp, media=(string)audio, payload=(int)126, clock-rate=(int)8000, encoding-name=(string)TELEPHONE-EVENT, will only receive

The frustrating thing is that when I build a dot file of the pipeline, it looks like the webrtcbin contains the red encoders and decoders, so I would think the best solution would be to somehow use those, without me repeating myself, but I don't know how to turn those on?
EDIT/UPDATE
The only way I can get my answer to put RED ahead of OPUS is by entirely removing the OPUS from the m-line.
If I then try to get-transceivers I don't seem to have the kind set until too late. If I set all transceivers to fec-type=GST_WEBRTC_FEC_TYPE_ULP_RED and do-nack=true, and then revert the video transceivers as soon as I can (during setting of ICE candidates, apparently), then I get the video pads added to webrtcbin, but a not-negotiated error. If I do nothing to the transceivers (hoping that they'll sort themselves out) or set the audio transceivers as soon as I have the kind, then the video flows, but I still get no audio-pad added and a warning about "Asked to create an answer without a remote description")

This is the best I've managed to get it working so far. I've changed my build methodology to remove
_pipeline = gst_parse_launch(ss.str().c_str(), &error);

And I now construct all my elements using factories, and then link them by hand. As soon as I construct my webrtcbin, I hook up to the add-transceiver signal. I then link the webrtcbin to first the video payloader, then the audio payloader. Each of those linkages causes the add-transceiver signal to fire, so I know that the second time it fires I change the resulting transcevier:
g_object_set(G_OBJECT(transceiver),
             "fec-type", GST_WEBRTC_FEC_TYPE_ULP_RED,
             "fec-percentage", 100,
             "do-nack", true, NULL);

I have to do it this way because the transceiver's kind remains unknown until streams start flowing, and that's too late. I continue to munge my SDP offer to put RED ahead of OPUS.
However, even with all of these actions taken, the answer produced by webrtcbin has OPUS in the preferred position. It has RED as a second choice, but that's the best it manages. Using Wireshark I'm fairly confident that I am then sending RED to my client (as the munged offer tells webrtcbin that's what the client prefers), but the client continues to send normal OPUS to me (as that's what the answer tells it to. Naively trying to munge the answer at any point just breaks things.
TLDR - progress, insofar as I can send RED from server to client, but I still can't convince the client to send me RED.
Update: I've managed to get RED being sent both ways, with the answer keeping RED in first place - but it requires recompiling gstreamer. For details, refer to my question on the gstreamer forums: https://discourse.gstreamer.org/t/problems-adding-red-to-audio-in-webrtc/2133
